# java api for XML - dom processing with disk backup

Tags: java, xml, large-files

I have a large  XML document (50G+) to process. Loading this to normal dom (saxon) require more than 160G. Not that much RAM or swap space.

Is there any library that provides h a disk based DOM tree? Any thing for Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, afaik all DOM implementations are memory bound.

You should use a streaming parser like [StAX](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/) or [Xpp3](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/xpp/).